# Unicode-math with LuaLaTeX (but not XeLaTeX) destroys spacing of my binary operator

Tags: math-mode, spacing, luatex, unicode-math

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\comptensor}{\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}}

%\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \[
        V \tensor_k W \qquad V \tensor W \qquad V \comptensor_k W \qquad V \comptensor W
    \]
\end{document}
```

The spacing looks OK (compiled with LuaLaTeX):

[image]

If I include the `unicode-math` package and compile with LuaLaTeX, it renders like this:

[image]

The completed tensor product looks nowhere close to symmetrical.

With XeLaTeX instead:

[image]

Looks fine. What is going on?

Is this a bug? If so, where should it be reported?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point :-)

Comment: the wording you are using is still unfortunate to say something is destroyed and showing surprise that behaviour is different misses the point that xetex and luatex have two more or less completely separate math layout engines, one for classic fonts and one for opentype math fonts, so any extent to which the behaviour appears to be compatible is due to active work by the engine or package maintainers, it isn't as if the spacing (using opentype) was correct and luatex or unicode-math made it not correct. It's rather that a combination of the two has not set the example as well as you hoped.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, I don't quite understand how I should formulate my issue then. Or do you say that it isn't an issue at all? To me it does not only seem odd that the spacing is not symmetrical, but also that putting a hat over `\otimes` changes the spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems to boil down to the fact that two \mathbin in a row gives a different spacing `$V \mathbin{a} W \qquad V \mathbin{\mathbin{a}} W $`. I see it in context too, which means the next message to the context list (after I checked for updates).

Comment: @JohnDorian no it is an issue, I'd say that the lualatex layout is less than ideal, but asking for something to be built is not the same as asking why something has been destroyed.