# Define a binary operator such that in displaymath subscripts are set below

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

At the moment I am using the following commands for tensor products respectively completed tensor products:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\comptensor}{\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}}}

\newcommand{\testline}{V \tensor_k W \qquad V \tensor W \qquad V \comptensor_k W \qquad V \comptensor W}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \testline
    \]
    \[
        \textstyle \testline
    \]
\end{document}
```

Both lines look like this:

[image]

I would like to change the definition of `\tensor` and `\comptensor` such that in textstyle nothing changes, but in displaystyle I would like the subscript to be printed *below* the operator instead of besides it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the natural syntax, so you can change your mind and avoid the underset symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tens}{\gen@tens{\otimes}}
\newcommand{\comptens}{\gen@tens{\hat{\otimes}}}
\newcommand{\gen@tens}[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar_{\gen@@tens{#1}}{\mathbin{#1}}%
}
\def\gen@@tens#1_#2{%
  \mathpalette\gen@@@tens{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\gen@@@tens[2]{\mathbin{\gen@@@@tens#1#2}}
\newcommand\gen@@@@tens[3]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \mathop{#2}\limits_{#3}%
  \else
    {#2}_{#3}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A\tens B\comptens C \quad A\tens_{k}B\comptens_{k}C
\]
\begin{center}
$A\tens B\comptens C \quad A\tens_{k}B\comptens_{k}C$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is precisely what I had in mind :-) Although I don't quite understand why we need so many of the `\gen@@...@tens`. Now I only whish the spacing was handled correctly with `LuaLaTeX` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429355/unicode-math-with-lualatex-but-not-xelatex-destroys-spacing-of-my-binary-opera) but that's another story...

Answer (score 5):

I did have to change the syntax just slightly, so that `\comptensor` takes an optional argument for its subscript, rather than using the underscore notation.

One cannot use the `\limits` style approach, because that only applies for the `\mathop` class, and not `\mathbin`.  Thus, I used a stack in order to get the `\displaystyle` underset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\comptensor}[1][]{
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\mathbin{\hat\otimes}\else\mathchoice
  {\mathbin{\ensurestackMath{\stackunder[1pt]{\hat{\otimes}}{\scriptstyle#1}}}}
  {\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{#1}}}
  {\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{#1}}}
  {\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{#1}}}
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\testline}[1][]{$#1 V \tensor W \qquad V \tensor_k W $\par
                            $#1 V \comptensor W \qquad V \comptensor[k] W$}

\begin{document}
\testline[\displaystyle]

\testline
\end{document}
```

[image]